# How to start the ad when opening the application

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a button who start ad when is clicked, but I want when application start to display the ad.
My code from the button is:

```
private void ShowReward_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrossMTAdmob.Current.ShowRewardedVideo();

        DonateBtn.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

Method `OnAppearing` not working for me.
The project is on iOS-Xamarin.
Is there a way to start `CrossMTAdmob.Current.ShowRewardedVideo();` when App starting ?

Comment: if it works from a button click there is no reason it should not work from OnAppearing

Comment: Give some example how to use OnAppearing ?

Comment: What do you mean by "The project is on iOS-Xamarin" is it Xamarin.iOS (xamarin native) or Xamarin.Forms project?

Comment: The project is on Xamarin.iOS

Comment: based on op's history, he is actually using Xamarin Forms.  And it has been previously pointed out to him that he is incorrectly tagging his questions.

Comment: I see, but maybe it is another project than previous questions.